# Can't get vue2-transitions package to work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get vue2-transitions package to work in my project but I can't get it to. This is what I have. Obviously I ran npm install before.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "vue2-transitions": "^0.3.0",
  },

<template>
    <fade-transition>
        <div v-if="visible">
            Some content here which I omitted for clarification
        </div>
    </fade-transition>
</template>
<script>

import {FadeTransition} from 'vue2-transitions';

export default {
  components: {
    FadeTransition
  },
  data() {
    return {
      visible: true,
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of variable **visible** is TRUE first make it false and then toggle it then it will work.

And no need to use the third-party library for transitions as Vue already providing the transitions feature inbuilt.

[See example on VueJs document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)